# Topological Vector Space not induced by Metric

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Can anyone give me an example of a Topological Vector Space that is not metrizable? I know that the neighborhood base of $0$ needs to be incountable, and all I can construct then is no topological vector space because the algebraic operations (especially multiplication) aren't continous.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prove that some topology is not metrizable](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888101/prove-that-some-topology-is-not-metrizable)

Comment: @TomekKania I don't think it's a duplicate. There's a difference between proving that some given topology is not metrizable, and coming up with the non-metrizable topology yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take for instance $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ with the product topology or the weak topology on an infinite-dimensional Banach space. You will find more examples [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888101/prove-that-some-topology-is-not-metrizable).

Comment: The product topology on $\Bbb{R}^\Bbb{N}$ **is** metrizable, in fact the topology is polish. You will have to take **uncountable** products.

Comment: product topology on $R^n$ sounds good. if possible i'd like to stick to a finite dimensional. so the product topology there isn't the same as the topology induced by the common norms?

Comment: Right, corrected.

Comment: oh, okay. that's what I suspeceted. thanks for the examples and the link

Comment: @Bananach: On finite dimensional vector spaces, the product topology is just the "usual" topology, so you will have to take an infinite dimensional example.

Comment: @PhoemueX, you need the space to be Hausdorff as seen [here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/locally-compact-topological-vector-spaces/). Otherwise any vector space equipped with indiscrete topology is not metrizable.

Comment: @ChesterX: Sure, thanks :) What I tried to get at was that the product topology of the usual topology on the factors $\Bbb{R}$ is the same as the usual topology on $\Bbb{R}^n$. The general statement is that

every Hausdorff topology on a vector space which makes the vector space operations continuous is the usual topology.

I also ommited the addition concerning the compatibility with the vector space structure before, for simplicity.

Comment: my question is fully answered by your examples and terry's theorem 2, thanks for the quick help everyone